# How to write a fully-expandable string slice in LaTeX3

Tags: expl3, expansion, latex3, strings

I am trying to create a LaTeX3 function that slices a string at the first `-` character.

So far I have

```latex
\cs_new:Nn \__slice_at_char:NN {
    \int_set:Nn \l__slice_pos_int {1}
    \str_map_inline:Nn #1 {
        \int_incr:N \l__slice_pos_int
        \str_if_eq:VnTF {#2} {##1} {
            \str_map_break:
        }{}
    }
    \str_range:Nnn \c_sys_jobname_str {\l__slice_pos_int}{\c_max_int}
}
```

However, if I run

```latex
\str_new:N \_a
\str_new:N \_b
\str_new:N \_result

\str_set:Nn \_a {fun-times}
\str_set:Nn \_b {-}
\str_set:Nx \_result {\__slice_at_char:NN \_a \_b}
```

`\_result` does no contain `times` like I would hope, but instead contains an unexpanded version of `\__slice_at_char:NN`. An alternative approach is creating a `\__slice_at_char:NNN` whose last argument is the name of a string variable to store the result in, however I was hoping to have a function that could be expanded directly to the result. Is this possible?

Comment: assignments such as ` \int_set:Nn ` can never be expandable, but you don't need any integers here.  essentially `\def\foo#1-{}`  then `\foo fun-times` expands to `times`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle That's much simpler! Would that macro def be considered the "LaTeX3 way"?

Comment: well `\cs_new:Npn` rather than `\def`

Comment: `\foo \c_sys_jobname_str` doesn't seem to work...

Comment: classically you would use `\expandafter\foo \c_sys_jobname_str` but in l3 `\foo:n` should be the base command then declare a `:V` variant so `\foo:V \c_sys_jobname_str` would act on the value of `\c_sys_jobname_str` rather than the token `\c_sys_jobname_str` itself.

Comment: `\cs_new:Npn \jason_gobble_to_hyphen:w #1- {}` and it's the LaTeX3 way :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

declaring a base `:n` function, with `e` and `V` variants

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn \qq_gobble_to_hyphen:w #1- {}
\cs_new:Npn \qq_split:n#1{\qq_gobble_to_hyphen:w #1}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \qq_split:n{ e,V }

\str_const:Nn\l_qq_str_a{fun-times}



1: \qq_split:n {fun-times}

\par

2: \qq_split:e {fun-times}

\par

3: \qq_split:e {\l_qq_str_a}

\par

4: \qq_split:V \l_qq_str_a

\par

\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is great! Can it be modified to gobble up to an arbitrary character stored in a string variable instead of just a `-`?

Comment: @JasonSiefken yes just define a helper macro that defines a version of `\qq_gobble_to_hyphen:w` (or `\foo`) using whatever so `\def\wibble#1{\def\foo##1#1{}}`  then `\wibble{-}`  would define `\foo` as above, `\wibble{+}` would do same but with +. again can use `_` names as required (which allows variants to be declared, the l3 naming isn't just for show)

Answer (score 5):

Just for the sake of variety, here's a LuaLaTeX-based solution. The user macro, called `\FindDash`, takes two arguments. The first, optional, argument is the "slicing character" (default value: `-`). The second argument is the search string which may or may not contain the "slicing character".

The macro `\FindDash` is fully expandable.

In the following screenshot, `..` denotes either that the slicing character occurs at the very end of the search string or that it wasn't found inside the search string.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\directlua{
   function find_dash ( s , c ) 
      nn = s:find ( c ) % check if 'c' is present in 's'
      if nn then tex.sprint ( s:sub ( nn+1 ) ) end
   end
}
\newcommand\FindDash[2][-]{\directlua{ find_dash( '#2' , '#1' ) }}

\newcommand\funtimes{fun-times}
\newcommand\ttt{t}

\begin{document}
.\FindDash{fun-times}. 
.\FindDash{funtimes-}. 
.\FindDash{funtimes}. 
.\FindDash[u]{\funtimes}. 
.\FindDash[\ttt]{\funtimes}.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Define a helper macro that does the discarding.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\slice}{m}
 {
  \siefken_slice:e { #1 }
 }

\cs_new:Nn \siefken_slice:n
 {
  \__siefken_slice_test:w {#1} #1 - \q_nil
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \siefken_slice:n { e }

\cs_new:Npn \__siefken_slice_test:w  #1 #2 - #3 \q_nil
 {
  \tl_if_empty:nF { #3 } { \__siefken_slice_remove:w #1 \q_nil  }
 }
\cs_new:Npn \__siefken_slice_remove:w #1 - #2 \q_nil { #2 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\jobname

X\slice{\jobname}X

\end{document}
```

[image]

If `\jobname` is `slice.tex`, there is no hyphen and we get nothing. If I run

```
pdflatex -jobname A-slice-test slice
```

I get

[image]